# What does "mole-faced" mean? This compound adjective often appears in crime noir stories and books

Tags: semantics

The internet is no help. It just shows me images of people with facial moles - and I'm pretty sure that's not what Sam Spade/Dashiell Hammett had in mind. Though here's a more recent example from William G. Tapply's "One-Way Ticket" (2013): *Once again the bald thug and the mole-faced thug gripped my upper arms.* Just down the page the latter thug is called Mole-face. Do they mean murine, as in with a pointed snout? That's a pure guess. But then, wouldn't it be "rat-faced"?

Comment: The way in which the thugs are referred to ("_the_ bald thug" and "_the_ mole-faced thug") leads me to think that the two characters have been more fully described earlier. If you look back a page or two can you find a fuller description?

Comment: Note that a mole is also : a spy (such as a double agent) who establishes a cover long before beginning espionage

Comment: Why would you think that *mole-faced* means *murine*?  Moles are of the family *talpidae*, mice are from several other families.  Why do you think *mole-faced* means anything other than *having a face like a mole*?   And don't worry if the anatomical correspondence between human and mole faces is somewhat approximate.  Surely, you would catch my drift if I wrote *a face like the southbound end of a northbound tram*.

Comment: in responsio ad Bold Ben, Good point! But since "mole-faced thugs" seem to be a staple of the genre, I hoped some noir fan might be able to clue me in on what it means. But I'm beginning to think Hi-Per Mark is right. He just looks like a mole .. who do appear rat-like, even if they aren't rats, per se.

Comment: @user66974 But what would "spy-faced" mean?

Comment: This is hardly a matter of opinion. Given that the term, as the OP says, appears in that literature with some frequency, it is reasonable to assume that its authors intended something **definite** by it, and expected their readers to understand it that way (perhaps because the term was also used colloquially outside the literature). Over time, the term has dropped out of use, and its intended meaning, therefore, may not be obvious to a present-day English speaker; explaining it is well within the purposes of this site.

Answer (score 2):

Your more recent example from William G. Tapply's "One-Way Ticket" appears on page 33 of that book. Looking at the text on [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/onewayticketbrad00tapp/page/32/mode/1up?q=mole), on page 11 we read:

> They were just, you know, thugs. One of them had a big **mole** or wart or something on his face.

and

> So I stopped and turned around, and he punched me in the chest. This was the one with the **mole** on his face.

On page 28

> He had a shiny round **mole** beside his nose. It was pink, about the size of a mothball.
>
> When you looked ta his face, it was hard not to stare at the **mole**.
> Dalt had said that one of the thugs who beat him up had a **mole** on his face.

and

> The guy with the **mole** got in beside me..

on page 29

> ..., and then the guy with the **mole** shoved me into the room.

Page 30

> My two escots, the guy with the **mole** and the short bald guy,...

and just before your quote, on page 32

> Paulie raised his head and looked over my shoulder to where the guy with the **mole** was standing.

and

> **Mole**-face was nodding and shrugging at the same time.

So for this book at least i think it safe to say that it does just literally mean a person with a facial mole.

Writers in the genre you reference probably have quite a high relative occurrence of characters who remain nameless, entirely or for a sustained period, and they have to be described, moles are one of the features that can readily be used to distinguish between nameless characters. With no specific instances cited for other occurrence of this descriptor, we can't extrapolate the same meaning with certainty in other books.

I assume you found the Tappley example via an online search rather than from reading the book, otherwise I fail to see how you could have missed the earlier references.

Edit: I can't find a references to Mole-faced people in Sam Spade/Dashiell Hammett, but there is a [mole-faced crook in the Dick Tracy cartoon strip](https://dicktracy.fandom.com/wiki/The_Mole#Dick_Tracy_in_B_Flat), whose nose is prominent, and his brow and chin recessive, giving him a mole-like look, which is handily illustrated here in his, appropriately, underground lair.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Moles (the animals) have very small eyes, hairy faces, low foreheads and long, upward-bending noses. If you imagine a human with the same features and put a black fedora hat on them, it's the perfect type for a gangster. The hat is there to hide their eyes in its shadow which makes the face look even more like that of a mole.

In a non-noir mystery, rat-faced villains would be more likely to appear but moles are black which makes mole-faced thugs the perfect color for a noir story. Note that they don't have to be Black as in race at all, because a mole's face is black because of the hair, so the villains face is black with facial hair reaching all the way to their eyes which makes them look even scarier.

Come to think of it, it would be foolish of any noir author not to have all their thugs mole-faced!

Comment: There's a long history of anthropomorphised moles going back certainly to The Wind in the Willows (1908); [here's a picture](https://hero.fandom.com/wiki/Mole_(Wind_in_the_Willows)?file=ImageTWITWMole1983.jpg) from a more recent adaptation, [here's an older, unclothed one](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Wind_in_the_Willows_pg_65.png) that might give an idea.

Comment: Superlative!! Thank you, thank you!!!!

Comment: If the lighting is perfect, just the tip of the nose will be out of the shadow of the hat brim, enhancing the effect (with pink skin).  It does appear to be easier to visualise the effect than to find an image of it. [This](https://previews.123rf.com/images/stokkete/stokkete1703/stokkete170300329/74379384-undercover-agent-holding-a-pistol-in-the-dark-1950s-noir-film-character.jpg) is close but the beard is too pale and/or catching the light a bit much.

Comment: I tried to draw a mole-faced thug: https://postimg.cc/DSdgTWj0